# How to do the query the result between two dates in Mondrian MDX query?

Tags: mdx, pentaho

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to query in mdx between two dates where the date is not exist in the cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049835/how-to-query-in-mdx-between-two-dates-where-the-date-is-not-exist-in-the-cube)

i have a question about the MDX on query the recored between 2 dates,say DateFrom and DateTo.

here is my MDX query (in pentaho):

```
WITH 
    SET [metrics] AS ${myType}
    SET [dates] AS (

                    [Date].[${DateFrom,date,"yyyy"}].[${DateFrom,date,"M"}].[${DateFrom,date,"d"}]

        :

                    [Date].[${DateTo,date,"yyyy"}].[${DateTo,date,"M"}].[${DateTo,date,"d"}]                    

    )
SELECT  
     NON EMPTY [metrics] ON COLUMNS,
     NON EMPTY [dates] ON ROWS
FROM 
    ${ActivityList}

WHERE  
    ([Product].[${Product}],[Subscription].[${Subscription}], [Operator].[${Carrier}].[${Distributor}], [Instance].[${Instance}])
```

and here is the mondrian xml file section:

```
<Dimension type="TimeDimension" highCardinality="false" name="Date">
      <Hierarchy hasAll="false">
        <Level name="Year" column="TS_YEAR" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Month" column="TS_MONTH" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Day" column="TS_DAY" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="Never">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
```

When I choose the DateFrom and DateTo in the user interface, but it didn't show any result even if there is some records bewteeen these 2 dates in the db. 
any idea?

Comment: Did you check that ``[dates]`` and ``[metrics]`` are not empty?

Comment: the [dates] and [metrics] was passed parameter in the pentaho report designer. I choose the value in the user console when viewing the report. so i think it should not be empty.  btw: how to check that if they are empty? another question is: is the syntax correct to query the result between two dates? thanks Benoit.

Comment: Hi Benoit, i am sure [metrics] is not empty, and for the [dates], even if i hard code it as "[2012].[7].[15] : [2013].[7].[15]", it didn't show anything in the result even if the database has a record with timestamp 2012-9-15, so i suspect the [dates] expression is not correct, but i don't know where is wrong since i don't have enough knowledge about MDX, any idea? thanks.

Comment: To check that your set expressions are valid, you can remove all the ``NON EMPTY``.

Comment: @Benoit i removed all the "NON EMPTY", but it seems that nothing is changed. Benoit, based on your experience, do you think is there any problem in the query?

Comment: I do not see any error in your query. Maybe there is a bug with the range operator? Try ``{[Date].[2012].[7].[15]}`` as expression for ``[dates]`` and remove again the  ``NON EMPTY``; your axes must not be empty.

Comment: @Benoit, I found the problem is because the MDX object is not found if I specify some date it didn't exist in the database. for example, if the database had the record, 2012-7-15 and 2012-9-15, if i specify the DateFrom and DateTo as 2012-7-15 and 2012-9-15, it works. but it didn't work if i specify them to other dates.  i want to make it work even if i specify the DateFrom and DateTo as 2012-6-15 and 2012-10-15, which the records was in the range, any idea? thanks.